# Confidence interval for Bernoulli sampling

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution, faq

I have a random sample of Bernoulli random variables $X_1 ... X_N$, where $X_i$ are i.i.d. r.v. and $P(X_i = 1) = p$, and $p$ is an unknown parameter.

Obviously, one can find an estimate for $p$: $\hat{p}:=(X_1+\dots+X_N)/N$.

My question is how can I build a confidence interval for $p$?

Comment: The wikipedia has details on how to calculate [confidence intervals for bernoulli sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval).

Answer (score 68):

- *If* the average, $\hat{p}$, is not near $1$ or $0$, and sample size $n$ is sufficiently large (i.e. $n\hat{p}>5$ and $n(1-\hat{p})>5$, the confidence interval can be estimated by a normal distribution and the confidence interval constructed thus:

  $$\hat{p}\pm z_{1-\alpha/2}\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}$$
- *If* $\hat{p} = 0$ and $n>30$, the $95\%$ confidence interval is approximately $[0,\frac{3}{n}]$ [(Javanovic and Levy, 1997)](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2685405); the opposite holds for $\hat{p}=1$. The reference also discusses using using $n+1$ and $n+b$ (the later to incorporate prior information).
- *Else* [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) provides a good overview and points to Agresti and Couli (1998) and Ross (2003) for details about the use of estimates other than the normal approximation, the Wilson score, Clopper-Pearson, or Agresti-Coull intervals. These can be more accurate when above assumptions about $n$ and $\hat{p}$ are not met.

R provides functions [`binconf {Hmisc}`](http://www.stat.ucl.ac.be/ISdidactique/Rhelp/library/Hmisc/html/binconf.html) and [`binom.confint {binom}`](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/binom/html/binom.confint.html) which can be used in the following manner:

```
set.seed(0)
p <- runif(1,0,1)
X <- sample(c(0,1), size = 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1-p, p))
library(Hmisc)
binconf(sum(X), length(X), alpha = 0.05, method = 'all')
library(binom)
binom.confint(sum(X), length(X), conf.level = 0.95, method = 'all')
```

---

[Agresti, Alan; Coull, Brent A. (1998). "Approximate is better than 'exact' for interval estimation of binomial proportions". The American Statistician 52: 119–126.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2685469)

[Jovanovic, B. D. and P. S. Levy, 1997. A Look at the Rule of Three. The American Statistician Vol. 51, No. 2, pp. 137-139](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2685405)

[Ross, T. D. (2003). "Accurate confidence intervals for binomial proportion and Poisson rate estimation". Computers in Biology and Medicine 33: 509–531.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016%2FS0010-4825%2803%2900019-2)

Comment: (+1) Nice answer.  This will become a reference for similar questions in the future, I think.  However, cross-posting is unusual; in fact, I believe it is frowned on, because it screws up many aspects of the feedback/referencing/threading/commenting system.  Please consider removing one of the copies and replacing it by a link in a comment.

Comment: @whuber thanks for the feedback. I have removed the other copy.

Comment: In the first formula, what are z1 and alpha?

Comment: I found the answer to my own question: $z_{1-\alpha/2}$ is the ${1-\alpha/2}$ percentile of the standard normal distribution and $\alpha$ is the error percentile. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

Comment: Should that be $3/n$ on the confidence interval for the second bullet point?

Comment: @JuanA.Navarro You are correct. Thanks for pointing that out; since $n/3>1$, hopefully no one has gotten too far with this error.

Comment: I was wondering if a binomial test could be correct [**in this case**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319687/does-a-binomial-test-apply-here)?

Comment: Why not simply using `binom.test()` in `R` which implements the Clopper-Pearson method?

Answer (score 14):

### Maximum likelihood confidence intervals

The normal approximation to the Bernoulli sample relies on having a relatively large sample size and sample proportions far from the tails. The maximum likelihood estimate focuses on the log-transformed odds and this provides non-symmetric, efficient intervals for $p$ that should be used instead.

Define the log-odds as $\hat{\beta}_0 = \log(\hat{p}/(1-\hat{p}))$

A 1-$\alpha$ CI for $\beta_0$ is given by:

$$\text{CI}(\beta_0)_\alpha = \hat{\beta}_0 \pm \mathcal{Z}_{\alpha/2} \sqrt{1/(n\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}$$

And this is back transformed into a (non-symmetric) interval for $p$ with:

$$\text{CI}(p)_\alpha = 1/(1+\exp(-\text{CI}(\beta_0)_\alpha)$$

This CI has the added benefit that proportions lie in the interval between 0 or 1, and the CI is always narrower than the normal interval while being of the correct level. You can get this very easily in R by specifying:

```
set.seed(123)
y <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.35)
plogis(confint(glm(y ~ 1, family=binomial)))

    2.5 %    97.5 % 
0.2795322 0.4670450
```

### Exact binomial confidence intervals

In small samples, the normal approximation to the MLE--while better than the normal approximation to the sample proportion--may not be reliable. That is okay. $Y = n\hat{p}$ can be taken to follow a binomial$(n,p)$ density. Bounds for $\hat{p}$ can be found taking the 2.5th and 97.5-th percentiles from this distribution.

$$\text{CI}_\alpha = (F^{-1}_{\hat{p}}(0.025), F^{-1}_{\hat{p}}(0.975))$$

Rarely possible by-hand, an *exact* binomial confidence interval can be obtained for $p$ using computational methods.

```
qbinom(p = c(0.025, 0.975), size = length(y), prob = mean(y))/length(y)
[1] 0.28 0.47
```

### Median unbiased confidence intervals

And if $p$ is 0 or 1 exactly, a median unbiased estimator can be used to obtain non-singular interval estimates based on the median unbiased probability function.  You can trivially take the lower bound of the all-0 case as 0 WLOG. The upper bound is any proportion $p_{1-\alpha/2}$ that satisfies:

$$p_{1-\alpha/2} : P(Y = 0)/2 + P(Y > y) > 0.975$$

This is also a computational routine.

```
set.seed(12345)
y <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.01) ## all 0
cil <- 0
mupfun <- function(p) {
  0.5*dbinom(0, 100, p) + 
    pbinom(1, 100, p, lower.tail = F) - 
    0.975
} ## for y=0 successes out of n=100 trials
ciu <- uniroot(mupfun, c(0, 1))$root
c(cil, ciu)

[1] 0.00000000 0.05357998 ## includes the 0.01 actual probability
```

The last two methods are implemented in the `epitools` package in R.

Comment: For reference: I believe the last type of confidence interval (median unbiased ci) is also called (Clopper-Pearson) mid-P confidence interval (see [Agresti & Gottard (2005)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20061194)).

Answer (score 2):

The [Wilson score interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval) performs well in general for inference for the binomial probability parameter.  The performance of various confidence intervals is examined in [Brown, Cai and DasGupta (2001)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2676784) and the Wilson score interval performs well compared to other intervals; in particular, it performs better than the Wald interval.  The Wilson score interval has a number of useful consistency properties and it can be extended to handle both finite and infinite populations (see [O'Neill 2021](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2109/2109.12464.pdf) for details).

The Wilson score interval can be implemented for finite or infinite populations in `R` using the `CONF.prop` function in the [`stat.extend` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stat.extend/index.html).  In the code below we give a simple example of a 95% confidence interval for the probability parameter for an infinite superpopulation.  To obtain a confidence interval for the proportion quantity in a finite population (either the full population or the unsampled part) you can add inputs for the population size `N` and the logical value `unsampled`.

```
#Set parameters
n <- 40
p <- 0.15

#Generate some binary data
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(c(0,1), size = n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1-p, p))

#Generate a 95% confidence interval for probability parameter
library(stat.extend)
CONF.prop(x, alpha = 0.05)

        Confidence Interval (CI) 
 
95.00% CI for proportion parameter for infinite population 
Interval uses 40 binary data points from data x with sample proportion = 0.1500 

[0.0706118771732036, 0.290723243664897]
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $X_1,...,X_n$ is a sample of successes and failures from a Bernoulli population with probability of success $p$, and we are asked to find a 75% confidence interval for $p$.

One solution is to invert the CDF of a binomial distribution.  Since $Y=\sum X_i\sim \text{Binomial}(n,p)$ we can define a $100(1-\alpha)\%$ confidence interval for $p$ as $$\bigg\{p:F_Y(y;n,p)\ge\alpha/2 \text{ and } 1-F_Y(y-1;n,p)\ge\alpha/2  \bigg\}$$
where $F_Y(y;n,p)=P(Y\le y)$ is the CDF of $Y$.

An approximate solution is to note that $\text{Var}[\sum X_i]=np(1-p)\implies\text{Var}[\bar{X}]=p(1-p)/n$, where $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum X_i$, and construct a $100(1-\alpha)\%$ confidence interval for $p$ by inverting a Wald test $$\bigg\{p: \Phi\bigg(\frac{\bar{x}-p}{\bar{x}(1-\bar{x})}\bigg)\ge \alpha/2 \text{ and } 1-\Phi\bigg(\frac{\bar{x}-p}{\bar{x}(1-\bar{x})}\bigg)\ge \alpha/2\bigg\}$$ $$= \bar{x}\pm z_{1-\alpha/2}\hat{\text{se}}$$
where $\hat{\text{se}}=\sqrt{\bar{x}(1-\bar{x})/n}$, $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the CDF of a standard normal distribution, and $z_{1-\alpha/2}$ is the $(1-\alpha/2)^{th}$ percentile of the standard normal distribution.  The Wald test approximates the binomial sampling distribution of $\sum X_i$, or equivalently the distribution of $\bar{X}$, using a normal distribution and expresses it in terms of the standard normal CDF.

For example, if you observed $y=\sum x_i=6$ out of $n=10$ trials, $\bar{x}=0.6$.  The $75\%$ confidence interval from inverting the binomial CDF is (0.37, 0.8).  If $p$ is truly $0.37$ we would observe a result as or more extreme than $\bar{x}=0.6$ only $12.5\%$ of the time.  Likewise, if $p$ is truly $0.8$ then $12.5\%$ of the time would we would observe a result as or more extreme than $\bar{x}=0.6$.  In this way we are $75\%$ confident that the unknown fixed true $p$ is in $(0.37, 0.8)$.  Intervals constructed in this manner will cover the unknown fixed true $p$ $75\%$ of the time in repeated sampling, and ours is one such sample.  The confidence interval from inverting a Wald test is (0.42, 0.78).

$$\text{Inverting Binomial Sampling Distribution CDF} $$
$$\text{(PMF Depicted Below)}$$
[image]

[image]

$$\text{Inverting Normal CDF Approximating X-bar Sampling Distribution} $$
$$\text{(Normal Density Depicted Below)}$$
[image]

$$\text{One-sided P-value from Inverting Binomial CDF} $$
[image]

The confidence curve above shows p-values and confidence intervals of all levels from inverting the binomial CDF.