# confidence intervals for probabilities of a biased die

Tags: probability, bayesian, inference

Given a biased die with d faces, you are given results of n die rolls.  I need to calculate the confidence intervals of the probabilities of each of the d outcomes of the die.

A solution in R! - even better.

Comment: If you just need individual confidence intervals, your question is answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4756.  Are you therefore implying you need a simultaneous confidence region?

Comment: don't think I know enough to follow that solution.  is there a simple R implementation as a function of d and n?

Comment: Simple (one-line) `R` implementations are provided in answers in that thread.

Comment: sorry for the novice follow-up question:  the answer is for fail/success Bernoulli trials.  so, if I want to the CI for the probability of outcome "5" for a 5-faced die.  I would classify "1" through "4" as "fail" and "5" as "success" and then apply the methodology in the answer?

Comment: That's exactly right.  You would need to repeat that procedure for each possible value of the die.