# Confidence Interval for binomial with known sample size and success probability

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test

I have a portfolio and I know how many loans the portfolio has in total $n$ and how many loans in the portfolio defaulted $d$. I also predicted one default rate for the portfolio $edf$. Hence, I am assuming the portfolio has a Binomial distribution with parameters $B(n, edf)$.

I calculate a realized default rate $rdf$ as $\frac{d}{n}$. Now I would like to calculate a confidence interval with confidence level $\alpha$ which shows where $\alpha$ percent of realizations from $B(n, edf)$ should fall. I want to take this confidence interval as an indicator if my model is working correctly, which means checking if $rdf$ falls within the confidence interval or not.

**Option 1: Applying cumulative distribution function**

Can I just use the cumulative distribution of the binomial distribution at $cdf_{binomial}(n, edf, \frac{(1 - \alpha)}{2})$ and $cdf_{binomial}(n, edf, 1 - \frac{(1 - \alpha)}{2})$?

OR

**Option 2 based on t-value**

Should I do sth like
$$
Y_{expected} \pm (t * s)
$$
where

- $Y_{expected} = n * edf$
- $t$ critical two-tailed t-value at $\alpha$ with $x$ degrees of freedom (How many degrees of freedom? How to calculate?)
- $s$ standard error $\sqrt{n * edf * (1- edf) }$ (Correct?)

Comment: Could you explain what a "range of a confidence interval" might mean and how it is computed or otherwise determined?  Is it related to your model in any way?  In what sense do you propose "using" a Binomial CDF?

Comment: @whuber. Thank you for your comments. I have updated my question.
- "range of a confidence interval" wrong wording for confidence level and therefore removed
- In what sense do you propose "using" a Binomial CDF? --> in Option 1
Can you please check if it is understandable now and let me know if not.

Comment: I think I understand it: you want to find a binomial confidence interval.  But isn't your question answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4756/confidence-interval-for-bernoulli-sampling/6184#6184?